# A lot of matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix

So I have a set of 15 $4\times 4$ matrices which I call $X_i, (i=1,2..15)$ and a set of 6 $4\times 4$ matrices which I call $y_j, (j=1,2...6)$. Now I have to calculate $(X_i y_j)-(y_j X_i^*)$ for different values of $i$ and $j$, where $*$ stands for Complex conjugate. 
Is there a simple command (with perhaps loops) in mathematica using which I can calculate all the 90 results instead of multiplying these matrices individually 90 times?

Comment: Have a look at `Outer`.

Comment: Try `Outer[#1.#2 - #2.Conjugate[#1] &, X, y]`

Answer (score 8):

Define some matrices.

```
Xs = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {2, 4, 4}];
ys = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {3, 4, 4}];
```

Use `Outer` applied to the indices to produce your derived matrices:

```
Flatten[
Outer[#1.#2 - #2.Conjugate@#1 &, Xs, ys]
, 1]
```

`Flatten` provides your result matrices in a single level list.

Or to follow your naming convention of variable names with subscripts:

Define the number of Xs and ys:

```
numXs = 2;
numys = 3;

Flatten[Outer[
  Subscript[X, #1].Subscript[y, #2] - 
    Subscript[y, #2].Conjugate@Subscript[X, #1] &, Range@numXs, 
  Range@numys], 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`X` is made of sixteen 4by4 matrix. `X[[i]]]` is your `Xi`.

```
X = Table[RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], {i, 1, 16}];
```

`Y` is made of six 4by4 matrix. `Y[[j]]]` is your `Yi`.

```
Y = Table[RandomReal[1, {4, 4}], {i, 1, 6}];
```

I define a function for the multiplication you want:

```
fun[i_, j_] := X[[i]].Y[[j]] - Y[[j]].X[[i]]\[Conjugate]
```

Now I make a table out of this function. Each `i` and `j` gives one of the 16*4 multiplications.

```
result = Table[fun[i, j], {i, 1, 16}, {j, 1, 4}];
result[[13, 2]] // Dimensions
{4, 4}
```

Each element of result as you see is a 4by4 matrix.